# vc-storefront on IIS deployment

Tags: .net-core, iis, virtocommerce

I am trying to deploy vc-storefront on IIS server. I am following the YouTube tutorial given in below URL

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDpRec7_p7g

It works fine till I run publish command. The publish command runs successfully and the files gets generated in given folder. The command ran to publish the video is "dotnet publish -o "

In video, right after they ran this command they open a URL "http://localhost/admin" , which does not work in my case. Can someone please help me to get rid of this roadblock ? I am stuck at this point and don't know how to proceed.

Note: If you feel this is not right place to ask this question, please suggest where can I get some help regarding this.

Comment: Did you get any error? Try using FRT to trace the error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules.

Comment: hi @YurongDai, the publish command ran successfully without any error. All the files were generated as well.  But in video next step is to open the /admin panel which does not work in my case. May be I am missing something.

Comment: one more thing I followed other video tutorial and ran the /admin in a separate project (which was never mentioned  in the link I mentioned in my issue detail). There I was supposed to get the app id and secret key from admin,, but what I got was just an API key. Which again has become a roadblock.